# Chain requests and map on each object

Tags: node.js, json, express, axios

I am trying to perform multiple get requests based on a primary get request which returns a json. More specifically i am using express.js and axios along with pushshift API to fetch Sumbissions and their Comments.

The primary json looks like this:

```
{
    "data": [
        {
            "author": "[deleted]",
            "author_flair_css_class": null,
            "author_flair_text": null,
            "banned_by": "moderators",
            "brand_safe": true,
            "can_mod_post": false,
            "contest_mode": false,
            "created_utc": 1514766734,
            "domain": "self.selfimprovement",
            "full_link": "https://www.reddit.com/r/selfimprovement/comments/7nc42d/is_theres_any_value_in_retainingreviewing_the/",
            "id": "7nc42d",
            "is_crosspostable": false,
            "is_reddit_media_domain": false,
            "is_self": true,
            "is_video": false,
            "locked": false,
            "num_comments": 1,
            "num_crossposts": 0,
            "over_18": false,
            "parent_whitelist_status": "all_ads",
            "permalink": "/r/selfimprovement/comments/7nc42d/is_theres_any_value_in_retainingreviewing_the/",
            "pinned": false,
            "retrieved_on": 1514841211,
            "score": 1,
            "spoiler": false,
            "stickied": false,
            "subreddit": "selfimprovement",
            "subreddit_id": "t5_2qmbm",
            "subreddit_type": "public",
            "thumbnail": "default",
            "title": "Is there's any value in retaining/reviewing the past (through videos, photos, writing, etc) beyond nostalgia?",
            "url": "https://www.reddit.com/r/selfimprovement/comments/7nc42d/is_theres_any_value_in_retainingreviewing_the/",
            "whitelist_status": "all_ads"
        },
        { ....
        }
      ]
}
```

I have to get all the submissions and then pass the id of each submission to multiple requests so that i can get the comments of each submission. My code currently looks like this:

```
function getSubmissions() {
    axios.get('https://api.pushshift.io/reddit/search/submission/?&after=1514764800&size=10&subreddit=selfimprovement')
        .then(function(response) {

            const promises = response.data.map(comment => axios.get('https://api.pushshift.io/reddit/comment/search/?link_id='+comment.id).then(({data})=>data));

              return Promise.all(promises)
             .then(values => {
                 res.json(values);
             });
         })
         .catch(function (error) {

            console.log('Error: ' + error);
        });
    }
}
```

The result of this code is res is not defined.

Comment: There is no `res`. You should use this code inside middleware with `req`, `res` and maybe `next` or pass `res` explicity: `function getSubmissions (res) ...`

Comment: Yes, i have already solved that, but how can i return the values of the promises? Right now i am getting the answer like this  { data: [ [Object] ] },
  { data: [ [Object] ] },{....}

Comment: Nope. You have the correct response. This is a `console.log` feature. Use `console.log(JSON.stringify(values));` or `console.log(require('util').inspect(values, {showHidden: false, depth: null}))`to get all output.